# Django Orm gteater than a list of integers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am trying to convert a sql join query to django orm,
not quite getting how to do it.

**Models**

```
    class Author(models.Model):
        author_name = models.CharField(
            verbose_name='Author', primary_key=True, max_length=250)
    
        country = models.CharField(verbose_name='Country', 
                                    null=False, blank=False,
                                    max_length=250)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.author_name
    
    
    class Publisher(models.Model):
        publisher_name = models.CharField(
            verbose_name='Publisher', primary_key=True, max_length=250)
    
        pub_add = models.TextField(verbose_name='Address', blank=False, null=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.publisher_name
    
    
    
    
    class Book(models.Model):
        isbn        = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='ISBN', 
                                        primary_key=True)
    
        title       = models.CharField(verbose_name='Title',
                                        unique=True,
                                        blank=False,
                                        null=False,
                                        max_length=250)
    
        pub_year    = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Publish Year',
                                        blank=False, 
                                        null=False)
    
        unit_price  = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Unit Price', 
                                        blank=False, 
                                        null=False)
        
        authors      = models.ForeignKey(Author,
                                        verbose_name='Author of book',
                                        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    
        publishers   = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, 
                                        verbose_name='Publisher of book', 
                                        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

**Sql Query is**
`select distinct B1.title  from Book B1, Book B2  where B1.unit_price > B2.unit_price  and B2.pub_year = 2004;`

**django query I tried**

```
        qs = Book.objects.filter(
            pub_year=2004
        )

        qs = Book.objects.filter(
            unit_price__gt__in=qs
        )
```

**It gives this error**

[image]

I feel like this is actually really, really easy and I am missing some obvious thing, any guidance will be helpful.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

*i was tinkering with it was have come up with this*

```
price_list = Book.objects.filter(
    pub_year=2004
).values_list('unit_price', flat=True)

price_list = list(price_list)

price_list = sorted(price_list)

# qs = Book.objects.filter(
#     unit_price__gt__in=qs
# )

# return qs

qs = Book.objects.filter(unit_price__gt=price_list[0])

return qs
```

feel like this is really inefficient

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you are trying to check here.
Lets assume you have 10 different prices in price_list.
[10, 20, 30, 40...]
Do you want all of the book that cost less than 10? or do you want all of the books that are in the range of  10 <=book <= 100

Comment: what i am trying to do is "display the books that have price greater than at least one book published in 2004"  i wrote the sql join query for it

Comment: At least one book, means the "cheapest" book. why not fetch the cheapest book in 2004, and fetch all books that their price is higher than that one?

Comment: what i want to do is get ANY book that from boss table that has price greater than at least one book published in 2004, so greater than any one of the items in the list will do.

Comment: I'll provide an answer with a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, it seems that it's sufficient to change the condition to be, fetch any book in the Book table, that its price is higher than any book that was published in 2004.

This can be done in the following way:
min_unit_price =

```
book_with_lowest_price_in_2004 = Book.objects.filter(pub_year=2004).aggregate(Min('unit_price')).get('unit_price__min']) # will provide the book with the lowest price in 2004
books_results = Book.objects.filter(unit_price__gt=book_with_lowest_price_in_2004)
```

Comment: Thanks perfect! i forgot about the aggregate and the Min
you have a typo get('unit_price__min'])